# Creating AJAX data string

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm submitting a form via AJAX to a PHP script that sends an email to me with the form details. The form is pretty straight forward, except that I have a group of checkboxes that signify the type of project(s) the person filling out the form wants. I know how to assemble a datastring with a simple form, but I am having difficulty figuring out the best approach to adding the checkboxes with name equal to projecttype[]. In theory, I think I want something like:

```
website=example.com&projecttype=1,2,4,6&budget=$500-$1000.
```

You can find the form and Javascript in this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5MF8/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a function exactly for that purpose: [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). It takes every element in your form and creates a query string. The below snippet should be enough.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/bin/send_form_email.php",
    data: $('#contactform').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
    //    ...
    },
    return false;
  });   
});
```

Comment: .serialize() gives me &projecttype=1&projecttype=5&projecttype=6. What's the best approach to reassembling the projecttype variable in PHP?

Comment: That's not what I get. I get `projecttype[]=1&projecttype[]=2` etc. It should be accessible as an array `$_POST['projecttype']` from PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the field name, but its the same. OK I'll try that out, thanks.

Comment: If that's what you're getting, I suggest you upgrade your browser and possibly whatever JavaScript debugging tool you're using.